# php: read dir with images and create style-rule with position based on filename?

Tags: php, css, image

I'm not much of a php junkie so I need your help in creating the best and simplest solution for this. I have a folder "path/images/headers" where I have multiple header images (all cut to the right size). The filenames look like this "something_right.jpg" , "xyz_left.jpg", "dfjakdfjs_center.jpg", etc.

I need a way to read this folder, provide a random image file and finally create a style rule that sets this image as background value and sets the background-X position based on the _underscore value of the filename!

```
<?php
    function header_image() {

        $imgDir = bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/headers;
        $pos = 
        return "transparent url('images/headers/" . $img . "') no-repeat " . $pos . " center;"

    }
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .header-image {
            background: <?php echo header_image(); ?>
        }
    </style>
```

So imagine I have "xyz_right.jpg" the style rule should look like this:

```
background: transparent url('images/headers/xyz_right.jpg') no-repeat right center;
```

Any idea what's the best solution to do so?

Comment: That code doesn't seem valid. You're exiting out of PHP on the first line of the function, but then you have more PHP without reopening a PHP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a lot to this, you need a way to point to each file ([DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class might help here, especially the [getBasename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getbasename.php) method) and a way to get the value from the file name (I would opt for [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to search the string for each condition).

How many files are in/will be in the folder?

Comment: maybe 20 images or so. I just need to read its filenames, extract the _underscore value at the end and create this style-rule.

Comment: But how are you determining which file to choose?

Comment: randomly! some random script should do it!

Comment: Take look at the things I have suggested, rand() can help to generate the random number, use that to select a file from the DirectoryIterator->getBasename(), and run that through a function that searchs for the key words (central, left, right), prob best to use a switch...case here. Bing bang bosh.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `glob`, `shuffle` and `preg_match`, not `DirectoryIterator` and `strpos`.